# Create a bar-chart from a date column plotting the number of occurances per month

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Every time I fire up Excel I find myself thinking why the heck everything is so unclear to work with. From a PHP developers perspective I often find myself copying data to csv-files and process them with PHP-logic to get to the desired result.

Right now I'm trying to create a simple graph and by all means I have literally no clue how Excel expects me to do this...

I have a column with 520 dates and all I want is to plot in a bar chart how many rows/occurances each month has. In PHP I would loop through the results and keep a count for each month and then displayin the results. How can this be done in Excel?

Comment: From an Excel users perspective, every time I work with PHP I find myself thinking why the heck everything is so unclear to work with. :-P **Anyway**, are the dates sequential or just randomly ordered? Can you give us an example of your data?

Comment: You can either use a pivot table and tell it to group the data by year & month OR you can set up a table with one row for each month and then use formulas to pull in the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can only plot data that you have - that is - you haven't created any data that includes occurrances yet. You need to create the mapping of dates to the count of their occurrances. You can do this using formulas but I would suggest a pivot table

Just give your column a header, highlight the data (inc. header) and select insert>pivot table. Put your data into the row and values sections of your pivot table and then you'll have the data. From this point you can create a normal bar chart selecting the relevant data insert > column ..

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the easiest way to do this is using a Pivot Chart.

If your data looks like this:

[image]

Then a Pivot Chart configuration like this:

[image]

Will yield the histogram that you want:
[image]